# How to get values from users objec?

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code how to get names of the below JSON responses from users object.want to display the names and setting to the spinner adapter.

can anyone help me

expected output:

```
Admin Administrator
Ganeshprasad S etc
```

response:

```
    {
  "name": "assigned_user_id",
  "label": "Assigned To",
  "mandatory": true,
  "type": {
    "name": "owner",
    "users": {
      "19x1": "Admin Administrator",
      "19x5": "Ganeshprasad S",
      "19x6": "Balaji RR",
      "19x7": "Kiran Thadimarri",
      "19x8": "Sridhar Balakrishnan",
      "19x9": "Shilpa MK",
      "19x10": "Velmurugan N",
      "19x11": "Aamir Khanna",
      "19x12": "Jamir Abbas Pinjari",
      "19x13": "Syed Shadab Ashraf",
      "19x14": "Shahul Hameed",
      "19x15": "Manjula C",
      "19x16": "Keerthi Vasan L",
      "19x17": "Lochan Jyoti Borgohain",
      "19x18": "Rajkumar Sanatomba Singh",
      "19x19": "Krishna Pandey",
      "19x20": "Nabajit Pathak",
      "19x21": "Manoranjan Ningthoujam",
      "19x22": "Pravin Karbhari Ahire",
      "19x23": "Pratap Kumar Choudhary"
    }
  }
}
```

below is code .nothing was displaying for the spinner

java:

```
if (name.equals("assigned_user_id")) {
                                            String jsondata ="";
                                            try {
                                                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsondata);
                                                JSONObject type = jsonobj.getJSONObject("type");
                                                JSONObject usr = type.getJSONObject("users");
                                                Iterator<String> keys = usr.keys();
                                                while(keys.hasNext()) {
                                                    String key = keys.next();
                                                    if (jsonobj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                                        String v = usr.getString("19x1");

                                                       account_manger.add(v);
                                                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, account_manger);
                                                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                                        spinneraccountManager.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
```

Comment: Do you have any control on the format of the json output?

Comment: I did not get?.....

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say your JSON data is in String

```
String jsondata ;
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsondata);
```

Since this json object has many properties so we will get the property "type" which is of type Object, So we will create another object of JSONObject

```
JSONObject type = jsonobj.getJSONObject("type");
```

Inside this type json object we have two properties name and users and in which user is another object, so we will get users object from type object

```
JSONObject usr = jsonobj.getJSONObject("users");
Iterator<String> keys = usr.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        //print here      
    }
}


//   String n1 = usr.getString("19x1");
   // String n2 = usr.getString("19x5");
   // String n3 = usr.getString("19x6");
//and So on......
```

Create XML for Spinner Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >  


<Spinner  
    android:id="@+id/spinner"  
    android:layout_width="149dp"  
    android:layout_height="40dp"  
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"  
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"  
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"  
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"  
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />
```

And the MainActivity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {  
String[] names = { n1,n2,n3};  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it  
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the  list  
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);  
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
    spin.setAdapter(aa);  

}  

//Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected  
@Override  
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),names[position] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}  
@Override  
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```

Comment: String n1 = usr.getString("19x1"); it is hard coded data

Comment: you can iterate over the keys and get the value

Comment: String n1 = usr.getString("19x1");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208861/discussion-between-jyothi-dadi-and-wahdat-kashmiri).

Answer (score 2):

```
String response = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"assigned_user_id\",\n" +
            "  \"label\": \"Assigned To\",\n" +
            "  \"mandatory\": true,\n" +
            "  \"type\": {\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"owner\",\n" +
            "    \"users\": {\n" +
            "      \"19x1\": \"Admin Administrator\",\n" +
            "      \"19x5\": \"Ganeshprasad S\",\n" +
            "      \"19x6\": \"Balaji RR\",\n" +
            "      \"19x7\": \"Kiran Thadimarri\",\n" +
            "      \"19x8\": \"Sridhar Balakrishnan\",\n" +
            "      \"19x9\": \"Shilpa MK\",\n" +
            "      \"19x10\": \"Velmurugan N\",\n" +
            "      \"19x11\": \"Aamir Khanna\",\n" +
            "      \"19x12\": \"Jamir Abbas Pinjari\",\n" +
            "      \"19x13\": \"Syed Shadab Ashraf\",\n" +
            "      \"19x14\": \"Shahul Hameed\",\n" +
            "      \"19x15\": \"Manjula C\",\n" +
            "      \"19x16\": \"Keerthi Vasan L\",\n" +
            "      \"19x17\": \"Lochan Jyoti Borgohain\",\n" +
            "      \"19x18\": \"Rajkumar Sanatomba Singh\",\n" +
            "      \"19x19\": \"Krishna Pandey\",\n" +
            "      \"19x20\": \"Nabajit Pathak\",\n" +
            "      \"19x21\": \"Manoranjan Ningthoujam\",\n" +
            "      \"19x22\": \"Pravin Karbhari Ahire\",\n" +
            "      \"19x23\": \"Pratap Kumar Choudhary\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
```

**This the data class**

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof User){
            User user = (User )obj;
            if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getId()==id ) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**UserArrayList**

This is how you can get the data

```
 ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

try {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject type = jsonobj.getJSONObject("type");
            JSONObject usr = type.getJSONObject("users");
            Iterator<String> keys = usr.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();

                    String value = usr.getString(key);
                    User user = new User(key,value);
                    userList.add(user);
            }

            Log.e("value","value----"+userList);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**This is the spinner Adapter**

```
ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, userList );
        spinneraccountManager.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinneraccountManager.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                User user = (User) parent.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "User ID: "+user.getId()+",  User Name : "+user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: users is not arraylist